# proof that for any two independent variables X,Y: ρ(X+Y, X−Y)=Var(X)−Var(Y)/Var(X)+Var(Y)

Tags: probability

need your help, how to proof that for any two independent variables X,Y

ρ(X+Y, X−Y)=Var(X)−Var(Y)/Var(X)+Var(Y)

i tried to open the right side with Var(X)+Var(Y) = Var(X+Y) but im not sure if its the right way and how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition

$$Cov(X+Y;X-Y)= E[(X+Y)(X-Y)]-E(X+Y)E(X-Y)$$

Expand and solve. Then use the definition of $\rho$